# Keyword Not Passing in Function

Tags: python, django, django-models, keyword

I am working with django models. I want to pass a model field as a variable. Given my function:

```
from django.models import models

def updatetable(value, fieldtitle, tablename, uid, refname):  
    workingobj = tablename.objects.get(refname=uid)
    currentvalue = getattr(workingobj, fieldtitle)
    setattr(workingobj, fieldtitle, currentvalue + value)
    workingobj.save()
    return
```

I have tried:

```
updatetable(len(sr), 'posts_added', managementmetrics, startdtg, refname=update_dtg_start)

updatetable(len(sr), 'posts_added', managementmetrics, startdtg, refname='update_dtg_start')
```

and even

```
updatetable(len(sr), 'posts_added', managementmetrics, startdtg, {refname:update_dtg_start})
```

I get the error: Cannot resolve keyword 'refname' into field. Choices are: length_of_update, update_dtg_finish, update_dtg_start

I've tried switching out refname for **kwargs but still can't seem to get it to take the field value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in how you call this function: the function itself does not do what you want.

You need to change how you call `get`. Rather than passing in refname directly, you need to use the dict *there*:

```
workingobj = tablename.objects.get(**{refname: uid})
```

Now you simply call the function in the normal way:

```
updatetable(len(sr), 'posts_added', managementmetrics, startdtg, 'update_dtg_start')
```

(You should also consider renaming the `tablename` parameter: you are not passing a table name, which implies a string, but a model class object.)

Comment: Thanks man. That was driving me nuts. Appreciate the quick answer.